# Stream a specific song using Soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm still learning how to use APIs - this has given me trouble. I believe that my code is correct, but nothing happens when I try to stream a song using a simple JavaScript onclick function.

HTML:

```
<head>
        <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="good.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="playIt()">play adele</button>
    </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX',

    });

function playIt(){
    var sound = SC.stream("/emberwaves/adele-set-fire-to-the-rain-remix", function(sound){
        sound.play();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Making sure you've loaded the `<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>` is the first step

Comment: @SeanC you're right, there is a 404 error.

https://api.soundcloud.com/emberwaves/adele-set-fire-to-the-rain-remix?format=json&client_id=6040fb6bf08c52ea42cac250bb081b3e 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  

the song works fine, I think the way I am calling it is wrong, but I can't imagine how else to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the `resolve` endpoint to get the API URL for that track:

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/emberwaves/adele-set-fire-to-the-rain-remix&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2016 19:54:36 GMT
Location: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/43377447.json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]
Server: am/2
Status: 302 Found
Content-Length: 128
Connection: close

{"status":"302 - Found","location":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/43377447.json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]"}
```

Calling a GET request that URL, we can get the `id` for the track, which is `43377447`.

Change your JS to point at the `tracks` endpoint:

```
var sound = SC.stream("tracks/43377447", function(sound){
    sound.play();
});
```

[Working JSFiddle with your client_id.](https://jsfiddle.net/zk1f687f/)

Comment: Hey JAL, I appreciate you teaching me the resolve to discover the tracks endpoint, but I do not hear anything playing in your provided JSFiddle.

Comment: @Trevor Tested and working perfectly in Safari 9.0.2 and Firefox 35.  What browser are you using?

Comment: You're right, it does work in Safari and Firefox. I personally use Google Chrome. Any inclination as to why it doesn't work in the Chrome browser?

Comment: After a little research, I think that this problem stems from flash and Chrome compatibility issues. Thanks again for your help JAL.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering why in Chrome the stream doesn't work, according to this [issue](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/39), you should invert the real time messaging protocol to force Chrome use html5 instead of flash.

To fix this you have to change the JS into:

```
SC.stream("tracks/43377447").then(function(sound) {
    if (player.options.protocols[0] === 'rtmp') {
        player.options.protocols = player.options.protocols.reverse();
    }
    sound.play();
}
```